# Whenever I plug my headphones, I hear static noises

Tags: sound, laptop, soundcard, speakers

whenever I plug in the earphones (headphones) in my laptop it starts a static sound, which so annoying.
sometimes, for this sound, original media sound can't be heard!
note that my laptop's loudspeaker is out of date!
Secondly my headphone port is like a Mobile phone's port.
I mean, it has only one port for headphone+microphone.
I don't have a headphone like this.
so where is the problem?

My laptop is HP Elitebook 2560p

It is new and came from foreign country! It's loudspeaker was all OK before giving it to me. But now it's out of date.

Comment: Are you sure the headphone port works? Could you try under another operating system?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using and what other steps you took to check what the problem could be?. This might be a hardware issue or even a electrical issue (Not grounded for instance).

Comment: 3.5mm headset with microphone that fits Android / Blackberry / iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Open alsamixer and zero out mic and mic-boost levels from sound card options (F6 in alsamixer menu).